# Слово "пирожное"

Tags: морфология

Понятно, что слово **"пирожное"** склоняется как прилагательное, хоть и является существительным. А может ли это слово быть субстантивированным? Интересно, как эта единица языка появилась на свет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Субстантивированным прилагательным? Оно и есть таковое.
Появилось очень просто. Как прилагательное к слову "пирог", которое и сейчас вполне используемо (пирожный запах, начинка, тесто, поднос - и т.д.).
В принципе "пирожное" и есть меленький сладкий пирог, если исходить из исходного смысла слова: нечто печеное. Представление о том, что пирог - это обязательно кусок теста с чем-то в нем завернутым, появилось позже. Как и пироги жареные.

Кстати, насчет жареного, вареного и мороженого. А так же печеного, верченого, томленого, квашеного и прочих кулинарых шедеров русской - и не только - кухни. 
В этом ряду пирожное - исключение, поскольку образовалось от обычного, а не отглагольного прилагательного. Этим и объясняются особенности орфографии, особенно видные в сравнении, например, с "мороженым" и "мороже**нн**ым". Варианта написания "пироже(н)ное" не существует, поскольку нет глагола пирожить (или подобного).